# SlikSvn: 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command in cmd.exe

Tags: svn, path, cmd

Computer: windows 7 64bit
SlikSvn is installed. The System variables *PATH* has the bin folder set correctly:

```
 ...; C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin; ...
```

If I type "svn" in the Run dialog (by pressing WIN+R), I can see the svn.exe is called in the cmd window.
If I type "cmd" in the Run dialog, a cmd windows opens up. In that window, typing svn shows the error:

```
 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Typing *PATH* comamnd in the cmd window reveals the correct path as seen in the Enviroment Variables.

I even added a new System variables "SVNPATH" with "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin" in it, but it doesn't work neither.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really have a space between the semi-colon and the `C:` as shown in the question:

```
...; C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin; ...
    ^
```

If so, that's probably your problem (Windows will not trim such whitespace when searching the path fields).

Comment: I prefer to use the _short name_ of the directory when there are spaces in the directory name, or it's very long: `...;C:\Progra~1\SlikSvn\bin;...`. Why did MS have the bright idea of putting programs under the `C:\Program Files` directory? Why not simply `C:\Applications` or even `C:\Apps`? Shorter and no annoying spaces. There's a maximum of 250 characters in directory/file names which means putting C# projects under `C:\Documents and Settings\dweintraub\Data\VisualStudio` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: So I misread this comment as I was having the same problem as AZ. I thought you meant to put the space in, as I did not have one. I did and that actually fixed my issue; svn is now running as I type. Safe to say I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by quoting the path in PATH like so: "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn". One would think Windows would allow file paths with spaces but apparently not!